# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC. Why when I move the <main> element from _layout.cshtml to the index.cshtml breaks the css

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I move the  element from the _Layout.cshtml file to the Index.cshtml file in an ASP.NET Core MVC project, it breaks the CSS styling. But when I move back the  element to the Layout.cshtml with the full html structure, works fine.
All the styiling are in Bootstrap.

Thanks in advance

If the ASP.NET Core MVC project is primarily using Bootstrap classes for styling, moving the  element from the _Layout.cshtml file to the Index.cshtml file should not typically cause CSS styling issues, as Bootstrap classes are designed to be responsive and should adapt to changes in the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution xD
The problem was here:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
```

New version:

```
<div>
    <main>
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Do you understand why this fixes your problem?

Comment: Yes. The cause is the class="container-fluid". When you start a new project, in the _Layout.cshtrml you have this by default 

<div class="container-fluid">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

So I just removed the bootstrap styling.

Comment: Then I would edit your answer to make that clearer...anyone reading it (right now) would not understand why your solution fixes the problem.